# How do I fix this coding bat FizzBuzz code, it keeps returning null as first value

Tags: java

[image: Here is a snip of my code]

I don't know what is causing this error. I also tried to add

```
String[] b = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, start-end+1);
```

at the end but it kept saying it only accepts String[], int, int even though that is what I entered. Here is the full error: Error:

```
String[] b = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, start-end+1);
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> The method copyOfRange(String[], int, int) is undefined for the type Arrays

Comment: Did you check the API for the method you need? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: I'd guess you've written `Arrays.copyOfRange` in a class called `Arrays`. Try qualifying it as `java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange`.

Answer (score 0):

All of your cases are correct, but arrays are zero indexed.

Start with `int i = 0` or set `a[0]` yourself before the loop to the value you need (but, it seems you just want `i = 0`)

And the array size seems to just be `end-start`. Not sure why you add one. That would explain why there's one extra element in all your arrays

Comment: no, if end was 4 and start was 3, you would get an array with 1 element when in fact it should include some correspondence to the set {3, 4}

Comment: The parameters (1,2) returns an array of size 1. Your output clearly shows that as incorrect as the you have an array of size 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] fizzBuzz(int start, int end) {
  int temp=start;
  int i=0;
  String[] str= new String[end-start];
  while(temp<end){
    if (temp%15==0)
    str[i]="FizzBuzz";
    else
       if(temp%3==0)
       str[i]="Fizz";
       else
          if(temp%5==0)
          str[i]="Buzz";
          else 
          str[i]=String.valueOf(temp);
    temp++;
    i++;
      }
  return str;
}
```